# PHP mail() does not work on digitalocean ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, apache2, php, email

my tools:
server= digitalocean
domain= godaddy
installed 
apache/2.4.18
php 7.0.30
ubuntu 16.04

i have tried install sendmail and configure it as below:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

and configure the /etc/hosts

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

i am sure it contains 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myhostname
and i made

```
sendmailconfig
```

yes for all questions in sendmail config.
also restarted apache2 with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

it is not sending mail. can u help me?

i tried send mail with send.php
it contains:

```
<?php
$to = 'sendto@outlook.com';
$title = 'title of mail';
$content = 'hello from world';
$titles = 'From: sendfrom@outlook.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: sendfrom@outlook.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
mail($to, $title, $content, $titles);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digitalocean has shared ip for users therefore, outlook, gmail etc. put it in the blacklist. In summary, mail() function works but does not deliver the mails.